# Connecting to a File share with a flat file source in SSIS2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005, ssis

I have created a SSIS package in BIDS005 that uses a flat file source as the input. The file I am wanting to use doesnt exist on my local machine, or on the server where the package will be executed. The file exists on a file share on another server, however when I try to use the server path for example:

```
\\servername\fileshare$\filename.csv
```

I get an error message saying:

> A valid filename must be selected

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions problem.  Do you have a valid connection to the file containing the userID & pwd to connect to the share drive?

Is it a problem in the development environment, or only when deployed?

Comment: The problem only exists when its deployed, even though the SQLEXEC account that it runs under has access to the share

Comment: it seems to have an issue with finding the file when using the \\servername\fileshare$\filename.csv syntax. Yet if I run the package with a drive mapped to the fileshare using the U:\filename.csv syntax the package executes fine

Comment: OK, can you test it logged in as the SQLExec account and access the file with the \\servername syntax?  There may be something shut off about that type of access that has nothing to do with ssis

Comment: logged in a SQLExec I can open the file using \\servername syntax from the run command... really strange!

Comment: then it may be a limitation of SSIS.  Is there a problem using a drive letter mapped on the server?